# POST http://localhost:8080/Login 404 (Not Found)

Tags: vue.js, npm, recaptcha

I am completely new to backend and I am trying to send the recaptcha token to backend and verify it, but it raises 404 error, what is the reason and how to fix it? My npm server is running on port 8080.

frontend Login.vue:

```
<template>
<div class="Login">
    <h3>{{ $t('Login') }}</h3>
    <form v-on:submit.prevent="onCaptchaExpired">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>{{ $t('UserName') }}</label>
        <input v-model="loginForm.UserName" type="UserName" class="form-control" :placeholder="$t('UserName')" />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>{{ $t('Password') }}</label>
        <input v-model="loginForm.Password" type="Password" class="form-control" :placeholder="$t('Password')" />
      </div>
      <div class="d-grid gap-2">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">{{ $t('Login') }}</button>
        <vue-recaptcha 
        ref="recaptcha"
        @verify="onCaptchaVerified" 
        @expired="onCaptchaExpired" 
        sitekey="6LfCmnEhAAAAAIsEHJx8QXbUHIAvIsuuwQW4JGj_" 
        class="mt-3" />
      </div>
      <div v-if="showErrorMessage" class="recaptcha-error-message"><strong>{{ $t('recaptcha-error-message') }}</strong></div>
    </form>
  </div>
<template/>

<script>
import { VueRecaptcha } from 'vue-recaptcha';
export default {
  name: 'Login',
  components: { VueRecaptcha },
  data(){
    return{
      pleaseTickRecaptchaMessage: '',
      showErrorMessage: false,
      recaptchaToken: '',
      status: '',
      sucessfulServerResponse: '',
      serverError: '',
      loginForm: {
      UserName: '',
      Password: '',
      recaptchaVerified: false
    }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    
      onCaptchaVerified: function (recaptchaToken) {
      this.showErrorMessage = false;
      this.loginForm.pleaseTickRecaptchaMessage = '';
      this.loginForm.recaptchaVerified = true;
      this.recaptchaToken = recaptchaToken;
      const self = this;
      self.status = "submitting";
      self.$refs.recaptcha.reset();
      axios.post("/Login", {
        UserName: self.UserName,
        Password: self.Password,
        recaptchaToken: recaptchaToken
      }).then((response) => {
        self.sucessfulServerResponse = response.data.message;
        console.log('google response', response)
      }).catch((err) => {
        self.serverError = getErrorMessage(err);


        //helper to get a displayable message to the user
        function getErrorMessage(err) {
          let responseBody;
          responseBody = err.response;
          if (!responseBody) {
            responseBody = err;
          }
          else {
            responseBody = err.response.data || responseBody;
          }
          return responseBody.message || JSON.stringify(responseBody);
        }

      }).then(() => {
        self.status = "";
      });





    },
    
    onCaptchaExpired: function () {
      this.loginForm.recaptchaVerified = false;
      this.$refs.recaptcha.reset();
      if (!this.loginForm.recaptchaVerified) {
        this.showErrorMessage = true;
        return true; // prevent form from submitting
      }
    }

  }
}
</script>
```

api-index.js

```
import router from "@/router";
"use strict";
const router = require("express")();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const request = require("request");
const cors = require("cors");

router.use(cors());
router.use(bodyParser.json());

router.post("/Login", function (req, res) {

    if (!req.body.recaptchaToken) {
        return res.status(400).json({message: "recaptchaToken is required"});
    }
    if (!req.body.UserName || !req.body.Password) {
        return res.status(400).json({message: "UserName and password are required"});
    }
    const verifyCaptchaOptions = {
        uri: "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify",
        json: true,
        form: {
            secret: process.env.CAPTCHA_SECRET,
            response: req.body.recaptchaToken
        }
    };

    request.post(verifyCaptchaOptions, function (err, response, body) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({message: "oops, something went wrong on our side"});
            }

            if (!body.success) {
                return res.status(500).json({message: body["error-codes"].join(".")});
            }

            //Save the user to the database. At this point they have been verified.
            res.status(201).json({message: "Congratulations! We think you are human."});
        }
    );


});
```

I tried to add

```
import axios from 'axios';
axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:8090/"
```

in Login.vue, but it raises another error: POST http://localhost:8090/Login net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Welcome! I see you have `import router` and then a `const router`. Try to change the name of express from router to something else. And are you starting the node server and the vue app?

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned in your question that your server is running on port 8080, but your code snippets is pointing to port 8090 as the server.

404 Errors usually indicate that the resource you're requesting is not found, and this seems to align with the inconsistencies between the port numbers you posted vs the port number on your server. If this isn't the issue, then I personally can't tell without running the code on my machine.

Hope this helps!